# Find all black rectangles in canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Let's say I have an scanned paper with some black filled rectangles and I want to positionate all of them, getting their coordinates (X and Y) and their dimensions (Width and Height).

Is there any accurate algorithm which does what I need? I'm new to pixel processing with Javascript and Canvas and I need some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Identifying the x,y,width,height of all black rectangles involves these steps:**

1. Use `context.getImageData` to get an array of all the r,g,b,a pixel information on the canvas.
2. Scan the pixel colors to find any one black pixel.
3. Find the bounding box of the black rectangle containing that one black pixel.
4. That bounding box will give you the x,y,width,height of one black rectangle.
5. Clear that black rectangle so that it is not found when searching for the next black rectangle.
6. Repeat step#1 until all the rectangles are identified.

Here's example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/3m0dL368/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    #clips{border:1px solid blue; padding:5px;}
    img{margin:3px;}        
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var cw,ch;        

    // background definition
    // OPTION: look at the top-left pixel and assume == background
    //         then set these vars automatically
    var isTransparent=false;
    var bkColor={r:255,g:255,b:255};
    var bkFillColor="rgb("+bkColor.r+","+bkColor.g+","+bkColor.b+")";

    cw=canvas.width;
    ch=canvas.height;
    ctx.fillStyle="white";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    drawTestRect(30,30,50,50,"1");
    drawTestRect(100,30,50,50,"2");
    drawTestRect(170,30,50,50,"3");

    function drawTestRect(x,y,w,h,label){
        ctx.fillStyle="black";
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
        ctx.fillStyle="white";
        ctx.font="24px verdana";
        ctx.fillText(label,x+10,y+25);        
    }

    function clipBox(data){
        var pos=findEdge(data);
        if(!pos.valid){return;}
        var bb=findBoundary(pos,data);
        alert("Found target at "+bb.x+"/"+bb.y+", size: "+bb.width+"/"+bb.height);            
        clipToImage(bb.x,bb.y,bb.width,bb.height);
        if(isTransparent){
            // clear the clipped area
            // plus a few pixels to clear any anti-aliasing
            ctx.clearRect(bb.x-2,bb.y-2,bb.width+4,bb.height+4);
        }else{
            // fill the clipped area with the bkColor
            // plus a few pixels to clear any anti-aliasing
            ctx.fillStyle=bkFillColor;
            ctx.fillRect(bb.x-2,bb.y-2,bb.width+4,bb.height+4);
        }
    }

    function xyIsInImage(data,x,y){
        // find the starting index of the r,g,b,a of pixel x,y
        var start=(y*cw+x)*4;
        if(isTransparent){
            return(data[start+3]>25);
        }else{
            var r=data[start+0];
            var g=data[start+1];
            var b=data[start+2];
            var a=data[start+3];  // pixel alpha (opacity)
            var deltaR=Math.abs(bkColor.r-r);
            var deltaG=Math.abs(bkColor.g-g);
            var deltaB=Math.abs(bkColor.b-b);
            return(!(deltaR<5 && deltaG<5 && deltaB<5 && a>25));
        }
    }

    function findEdge(data){
        for(var y=0;y<ch;y++){
        for(var x=0;x<cw;x++){
            if(xyIsInImage(data,x,y)){
                return({x:x,y:y,valid:true});
            }
        }}
        return({x:-100,y:-100,valid:false});
    }

    function findBoundary(pos,data){
        var x0=x1=pos.x;
        var y0=y1=pos.y;
        while(y1<=ch && xyIsInImage(data,x1,y1)){y1++;}
        var x2=x1;
        var y2=y1-1;
        while(x2<=cw && xyIsInImage(data,x2,y2)){x2++;}
        return({x:x0,y:y0,width:x2-x0,height:y2-y0+1});
    }

    function drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
        ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
        ctx.strokeStyle="red";
        ctx.lineWidth=0.50;
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function clipToImage(x,y,w,h){
        // don't save anti-alias slivers
        if(w<3 || h<3){ return; }
        // save clipped area to an img element
        var tempCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
        var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
        tempCanvas.width=w;
        tempCanvas.height=h;
        tempCtx.drawImage(canvas,x,y,w,h,0,0,w,h);
        var image=new Image();
        image.width=w;
        image.height=h;
        image.src=tempCanvas.toDataURL();
        $("#clips").append(image);
    }

    $("#unbox").click(function(){
        var imgData=ctx.getImageData(0,0,cw,ch);
        var data=imgData.data;
        clipBox(data);
    });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="unbox">Clip next sub-image</button><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=150></canvas><br>
    <h4>Below are images clipped from the canvas above.</h4><br>
    <div id="clips"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @josemmo : try to make a least as much effort as the person answering.